# Python permutations of a list, storing value, without mutating

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I have a hard time writing permutations. Once I find a new algorithm, I bump into mutability. Is there a way to append into newArray, but keep old values untouched?

**Or how should I modify it?**

```
newArray = []


def permutations(array):
    if array in newArray:
        return
    for i in range(len(array)):
        array[0], array[i] = array[i], array[0]
        newArray.append(array)
        permutations(array)
    return newArray
```

Comment: You want to append the array without changing the array?

Comment: I meant without changing what was already inside. For ex.: 
newArray = [[1]]
newArray.append([2])     
newArray = [[2],[2]] 
This used to happen

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, the problem is that lists are mutable. The solution, then, is that you must make a copy of `array` instead of mutating the original. It should look something like this:

(*Edit*: changed to reflect grovina's comment that a shallow copy is sufficient)

```
newArray = []

def permutations(array):
    if array in newArray:
        return
    for i in range(len(array)):
        array_copy = list(array) # or array[:] or copy.copy(array); they all create copies
        array_copy[0], array_copy[i] = array_copy[i], array_copy[0]
        newArray.append(array_copy)
        permutations(array_copy)
    return newArray
```

Since you're modifying `newArray` (which is mutable since it's a list), it's also not necessary to return it at the end of the function, but that's up to you.

Comment: why a deep copy? I believe shallow copying would do.

Comment: I think you're right. My excuse is the less than 3 hours of sleep I got each of the past 2 nights...let's go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responses, I ended up with this:

```
def permutations(array):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return [[]]
    if len(array) == 1:
        return [array]
    else:
        arr = []
        for i in range(len(array)):
            array[0], array[i] = array[i], array[0]
            start = array[0]
            end = permutations(array[1:])
            for x in end:
                arr.append([start]+x)
    return arr
print(permutations([1, 2]))
```

Output:[[1, 2], [2, 1]]

Should work for any input.